# How to link UV Maps of the same objects when joining them?

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, objects

This will be a little bit difficult to explain but I have a problem. I have a pendant I made with gems and my question is if I made one gem created a UV map for it and added material in the shading tab, then I duplicate the gem with the same settings and join them together [ the two gems or more] it creates like 2 doubled the same UV map on each other, as they being UV map on each other the more I join gems, and my question is how you take all the UV maps and turn it into one map since they all have the same UV and material.. is it possible?

the mesh:https://ibb.co/QFZQ0dj

the uvmap as its shown white because theres a lot of uvmaps on each other : https://ibb.co/VJsgDyc

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to do.

Simply select one object and then the other object (before joining) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> > <kbd>Copy UV Map</kbd>.

[image]